# Is it possible to write a mobile app into micro sd card?

Tags: android, ios

If it is possible, can somebody explain how or show me any guide on how to do it?
I'm thinking of a private app from a micro sd card, if you plug in the micro sd card, then you can install and open/access the mobile app. I only need a method of how to write the app into the card, not how to create the app.
And is it possible to make it "online" like a forum or something?
I'm thinking of this MicroSD app because I don't want to pay google play or the app store to host it
If I'm wrong and it's not possible to make an "online" one, just correct me, thanks for your time and answers.

Comment: Not sure to understand, but google play cost 25dollara for life. if you want just an app for you and few user, then just give the apk. Who want install it, will do. Or just do a website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating your app, build it in order to create an apk file. Then, move the apk to the device and install it.

You can then move your app to the device's sd card. You can find [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/114667/how-to-install-android-apps-to-the-sd-card-by-default-move-almost-any-app-to-the-sd-card/) more info about how to install android apps to an sd card.

Also, you should know that Google Play and other such services are just a marketplace where you upload an app for easier distribution and downloading. So, you don't really need them if you don't want to share your app to be used by other android users.